# Debezium Ebedded cannot instatiate transformation 'unwrap'

Tags: postgresql, debezium, debezium-engine

I managed to stream CDC events from Postgres using Debezium Embedded version `1.6.2.Final`. Now I'm interested in flattening the events so only the `after` data is sent.

As per the following article: https://debezium.io/documentation/reference/1.6/transformations/event-flattening.html#_configuration

I assume these are the properties I need to include in my `Configuration`

```
        return io.debezium.config.Configuration.create()
                ...
                .with("transforms", "unwrap")
                .with("transforms.unwrap", "io.debezium.transforms.ExtractNewRecordState")
                .build();
```

Then I create my DebeziumEngine like below:

```
        this.debeziumEngine = DebeziumEngine.create(Json.class)
                .using(cdcConfiguration.asProperties())
                .notifying(...)
                .build();
```

When I run the application I get the following error on startup:

```
io.debezium.DebeziumException: Cannot instatiate transformation 'unwrap'
    at io.debezium.embedded.Transformations.getTransformation(Transformations.java:66) ~[debezium-embedded-1.6.2.Final.jar:1.6.2.Final]
    at io.debezium.embedded.Transformations.<init>(Transformations.java:44) ~[debezium-embedded-1.6.2.Final.jar:1.6.2.Final]
    at io.debezium.embedded.EmbeddedEngine.<init>(EmbeddedEngine.java:593) ~[debezium-embedded-1.6.2.Final.jar:1.6.2.Final]
    at io.debezium.embedded.EmbeddedEngine.<init>(EmbeddedEngine.java:81) ~[debezium-embedded-1.6.2.Final.jar:1.6.2.Final]
    at io.debezium.embedded.EmbeddedEngine$BuilderImpl.build(EmbeddedEngine.java:302) ~[debezium-embedded-1.6.2.Final.jar:1.6.2.Final]
    at io.debezium.embedded.EmbeddedEngine$BuilderImpl.build(EmbeddedEngine.java:218) ~[debezium-embedded-1.6.2.Final.jar:1.6.2.Final]
    at io.debezium.embedded.ConvertingEngineBuilder.build(ConvertingEngineBuilder.java:151) ~[debezium-embedded-1.6.2.Final.jar:1.6.2.Final]
```

Could somebody please point what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: did you succeeded ? I have the same issue with Debezium 1.7

Comment: Unfortunately I haven't investigated further as I left this on stand-by to work on other things, but I hope to come back soon. I'm also surprised nobody from the dev team answered. If you are also facing this, I wonder if it could be a bug and we should post it on GitHub